# iText - problem with line break character replaced by?

Tags: pdf, rtf, itext

I am working with code using iText.  We are upgrading from iText 1.2 to iText 2.1.5.  With the upgrade (no changes in the actual code), all the line break characters are being replaced with a question mark.  This does not happen when the text automatically wraps in the document, only when the data being fed contains a line break.  I am unsure if it is the line feed or carriage return causing the problem, or a combination of the two.  Interestingly, the same file can print to a PDF or an RTF, based on the user selections, and the character replacement only occurs in RTF.  Anyone know what can be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java, MyString.replace("\r\n","\n")

replacing all \r\n with line feeds and it seems to work.